# How to normalize OpenCV Sobel filter given kernel size

Tags: python, opencv

How to invoke OpenCV Sobel function to compute actual derivative of image given some kernel size? I.e. considering that image is a function of `f(x, y)` and `x, y` spans from `[0, 0]` to `[width, height]` in pixels?

```
dimg_x = cv2.Sobel(img, ddepth=-1, dx=1, dy=0, ksize=ksize)
```

Probably some scaling needs to be applied to gradient image, but I can't figure out how to compute it given kernel size.

Comment: The Sobel gradient is an approximation of the gradient. So, It depends on what is it that you call an "actual" derivative. All numerical methods are approximations. At some point you could simply take the difference in the horizontal or vertical direction of rows and columns respectively.

Comment: @Cyb3rFly3r by "actual" I mean by the definition. I'm ok that this is an approximation, but for some applications it is inacceptable that it is scaled like 100x times.

Comment: The definition of derivative requires a continuous function, which you don't have in a digital image, which is a discrete representation of some unknowable function. There are many ways to try to approximate gradient, probably Sobel is not what you are looking for. On of the simplest approaches would be to use numpy.diff along columns and rows.

Comment: @Cyb3rFly3r difference along rows and columns is first order approximation of derivative, considering that underlying function is linear. It's crude, susceptible to noise etc. That's why I'm using larger sobel kernels to get derivative. But they're not normalized in OpenCV, so I'm looking for a way to normalize them. If you look at finite difference coefficients (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficient) and coefficients in Sobel kernels on OpenCV you'll see that they differ greatly.

Comment: Sure, that was the point I was trying to make, probably not well explained; you can use a finite difference filter. For instance opencv `createDerivFilter` to do that. [Sobel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator) is not all that different, just not normalized.

Comment: @Cyb3rFly3r I knew what you've tried to say, sorry for being impatient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this snippet will do the trick:

```
def gradient(img, dx, dy, ksize):
    deriv_filter = cv2.getDerivKernels(dx=dx, dy=dy, ksize=ksize, normalize=True)
    return cv2.sepFilter2D(img, -1, deriv_filter[0], deriv_filter[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `scale` argument of `Sobel`:

```
cv2.Sobel(img, dx=dx, dy=dy, ksize=ksize, scale=2**(2+dx+dy-ksize*2), ddepth=CV_32F)
```

When you scale the output that way, you typically do *not* want to have `ddepth=-1` but rather get the result as floats or doubles.